# what error with my htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess

please help me to fix error on my .htaccess it return error 500

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /mvc/public

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [SQA,L]
```

Comment: Can you add details what is the expected behavior of your htaccess

Comment: thank koy CoderDude Twodee.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your flag in the RewriteRule. SQA is not a valid flag, but I'm assuming you meant QSA, so change SQA,L to QSA,L:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [SQA,L]
```